# How to execute a mysql script from a batch file, using a properties file to read the username and password

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I have a Batch file that executes a mysql scripit (Test.sql) but Im passing the user name and pasword from the batch, which I dont want to, Instead I want to read the username/ password from a properties file or text file. please can some 1 help. Below is my sample batch and sql file.

Sample Batch file :

```
@echo off
echo Starting Batch Job
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin
mysql --user=root --password=mysql123 --database=mydb -e "source C:\SHSTemp\SQLscripts\Test.sql"
Echo After executing the Sql
pause
```

This is the sample SQL script

```
use mydb;
select * from Test_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has support for client-side config files, see the manual here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html

They are `my.cnf` files and you can also put username and password in there.

Example:

```
[client]
user="user"
password="my_password"
```